# Ableton AlesisDM7 Midi Drims product sound but no notes

Tags: midi, ableton-live

I have a drum MIDI controller, and I used to be able to record the hits into midi notes just fine. Now, it might record 1 in every 35 hits. All intended hits come through the speakers, but nothing is recorded in the midi track. Weirdly enough, if I turn on each individual channel it also captures all the audio from the Plugin... just not the notes. Any ideas?

I have opened up the controller in another DAW and it has no problems producing noise AND capturing the notes. I assume there is an Ableton setting somewhere that I'm missing?

Screenshots:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/nL8Ow.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/aZ8Y4.jpg